# How to configure sharp so it can convert jpg/png to webp,avif and then compress them by 25%?

Tags: image, image-processing, optimization, compression, sharp

How to configure sharp so it can convert all jpg/png in 'src/images/' to webp,avif and then compress them by 25%? Also, I want to compress svg without converting. The result file should be in 'dist/assets/images/'. The Sharp's documentation is not intuitive, so it is quite difficult to understand for a beginner. This is what I tried to do (I know it looks incorrect, but that's why I ask solutions):

```
import sharp from 'sharp';

sharp('jpg, png')
  .toFormat('webp, avif')
  .webp({ quality: 75 })
  .avif({ quality: 75 })
  .svg({ quality: 75 })
  .toFile('dist/assets/images/');
```

P.S.
I'm using Vite, so maybe there's another easier way to do the same for Vite.

Answer (score 1):

https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-constructor

The api-constructor section of the docs is quite readable now with comments and code examples, if you still need anything from Sharp I'd recommend you check it out.

Sharp is a factory that takes a single file as an argument, with an optional options object. If you want to convert a jpg, you might have more luck using something like `sharp('filenameString.jpg').webp({quality: 75})` and then chaining your methods from there.

For your question, loop through all files in your desired path, and pass their filename as a string to sharp. Proceed with your method chaining from there.

Finally the `.toFile('.path/filename')` method doesn't just place it at that position in the path, it also names your file. You should use a unique filename for every file in that path so nothing is accidentally overwritten. This is commonly done using the Date() and concatenating the current time as a string with your intended filename. Ex.

```
const time = new Date().toISOString()
const ref = time + originalname + '.webp'
sharp('inputFilename.jpg').toFile('./path/' + ref)
```

Finally for some extra reading, I find DigitalOcean tutorials to be extremely good for learning new tools. Here's a DO article on using sharp https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-process-images-in-node-js-with-sharp

Comment: Using new Date().toISOString() is a bad idea as colon (:) is an invalid character in Windows & Mac systems. I would either use .toTime() or if I want a human readable name, replace invalid characters with valid ones by  .replace(/[^a-z0-9_-.]+/gi, '-')